# Фронтенд. Как за один ajax запрос обновить несколько блоков?

Tags: jquery, ajax, администрирование, frontend, rest

Друзья, нуждаюсь в совете.

Как за один ajax запрос обновить несколько блоков? Скажем, есть страница, на которой куча разнообразной информации из разных таблиц. И вот возникает необходимость всё разом обновить, без перезагрузки страницы. Говоря проще, в админке идёт работа с модулем, надо обновлять данные, а иногда и вовсе менять модуль.

Конечно, можно на каждый блок повесить свой ajax, но, по-моему, это нехорошая идея.

По всей видимости, нужно делать один запрос, данные получать в json и потом распихивать по элементам. Собссно, вопрос. Если это так, то как может выглядеть подобная реализация?
Какая должна быть структура json (понятно, что она должна в кой-то мере отражать содержание страницы), как происходит распихивание по элементам?
Делать всё ручками-джикверями, или предпочтительнее заюзать ангуляр какой-нибудь или бэкбон... товарищи, поделитесь опытом!

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@hcuser](/users/25423/hcuser)](/users/25423/hcuser), в ответе передаете массив данных.

```
$response = array(
   'first_block' => array(
        'title' => 'Заголовок блока 1',
        'text' => 'Текст блока 1',
   ),
   'second_block' => array(
        'title' => 'Заголовок блока 2',
        'text' => 'Текст блока 2',
   ),
);
```

В качестве ключей, можно использовать селекторы нужных блоков: классы, id и т.д. То есть, вместо "first_block" и "second_block".

Вот [простенький примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/0boe7wyp/1/) в песочнице.

Comment: Спасибо, друг. Не буду возражать, если ещё кто-нибудь поделится опытом.

Comment: Вопрос. Скажем, в целевом поле лежит список. Как принятно делать? Вернуть для него готовый хтмл код, или вернуть массив и на лету создать-добавить элементы списка?

Comment: @hcuser, вы спрашиваете о том, в каком виде лучше отправлять ответ с сервера?  Всё зависит от того, что необходимо с этим ответом потом делать. На стороне сервера, на мой взгляд, проще сформировать какую-то сложную html-структуру, нежели это делать на клиенте.